# creating data base in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to make my Sq-lite database globally accessible throughout my Android application using a singleton pattern:

What are some of the design options for the synchronizing the read/write of a sq-lite database in an android app -My question is how to design the SQLite DB access for the scenario

Comment: This is too broad a question to receive a proper answer but you should read though [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for a great introduction to SQLite database handling in Android.

Comment: Official tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1):

"using a singleton pattern " as you mentioned, it ensures that only one db connection  is made to connect to database.
It's difficult to answer your question, but i think at least there are some things you should 
try.
1. Extend the sqliteopenHelper for create database. -> This is the place you should apply the singleton pattern:
e.x:

`private DummyDBHelper  _instance = null;
    public static DummyDBHelper getInstance(Context mContext) {
         if(_instance == null) _instance = new DummyDBHelper(mContext);
         return _instance;`

1. implement the CRUD operations
2. Define each object seperately in each file
3. Call open/close in your activity